# function on click only occurs once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a map to zoom in or out on click. After the first click however, the map fails to zoom again. I'm using jquery animate right now, but if there's a better solution I'd like to know that as well.

```
  var mapWidth = $('.vector-map img').width();

  $('.zoom-in').on('click', function() {
    $('.vector-map img').animate({width: mapWidth + 50}, 'slow');
  });

  $('.zoom-out').on('click', function() {
    $('.vector-map img').animate({width: mapWidth - 50}, 'slow');
  });
```

Comment: Does it show an error message? Should you be using px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are only getting the map width at the initial setup, not each time before you zoom, try:

```
var mapWidth = $('.vector-map img').width();

  $('.zoom-in').on('click', function() {
    mapWidth = $('.vector-map img').width();
    $('.vector-map img').animate({width: mapWidth + 50}, 'slow');
  });

  $('.zoom-out').on('click', function() {
    mapWidth = $('.vector-map img').width();
    $('.vector-map img').animate({width: mapWidth - 50}, 'slow');
  });
```

Comment: If this answer helped you to solve your problem, please mark it as such, so that others can benefit from the answer as well, thank you and happy to help.